# JavaScript reference directives not working as expected

Tags: javascript, javascript-intellisense

I am seeing what appears to be inconsistent behavior with JavaScript [reference directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx#ReferenceDirectives). I am assuming that it is user error on my part, though, and would like to know what I do not know.

The folders in my project (happens to be an ASP.NET MVC project, but I do not think that makes a difference) are organized in this hierarchy:

```
Scripts
...MyOrg
......Models
.........Model1.js
......Support
.........Constants.js
.........Utility1.js
..._references.js
```

_references.js contains, among other references, this line so that I do not have to include a reference to Constants.js in each file that uses it ([reference about _references.js](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) by Mads Kristensen):

```
/// <reference path="MyOrg/Support/Constants.js" />
```

I have tried this alternate form as well that should not (and did not) make a difference:

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/MyOrg/Support/Constants.js" />
```

Both Model1.js and Utility1.js use an item from Constants.js, e.g.

```
var msg = MyOrg.Constant.Message103;
```

Model1.js is correctly recognizing that the reference comes from Constants.js per the reference in _references.js. But Utility1.js flags the use with a warning (*"use of an implicitly declared global variable 'MyOrg' "*) unless I add another, explicit reference directive in Utility1.js--either of these work:

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/NextIT/Support/Constants.js"/>
/// <reference path="Constants.js"/>
```

Why is Utility1.js not recognizing the reference from _references.js ?

Comment: Have you done `CTRL+SHIFT+J` to refresh your remote references?

Comment: Good thought, @CodeMaverick, but that did not help.

Comment: Darn ... the easy stuff is always worth a shot!